# System.Threading.Tasks.Task is not implicitly convertible to IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I'm experiencing a memory leak in my program which is apparently caused by DelayPromise tasks being started by the AngleSharp library. I am trying to fix this memory leak, and one of the solutions I'm attempting is to wrap the `Task.Delay` task in a `using()` statement so it gets disposed earlier. The problem I'm having is that `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` does not appear to implement `IDisposable`. I can see [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,146) that Task does indeed implement `IDisposable` in the .NET Framework source code, but I'm getting an error that `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` isn't implicitly convertible to `IDisposable` when I attempt to put it into a `using()` statement. I'm using .NET 4.6.1 on my project, and AngleSharp is using the compatible .NET Standard 1.0. What gives?

Comment: Are you awaiting the `Task.Delay`?  If you `await` it its no longer a `Task`.  In either case it would help to see your code.

Comment: yeah, can you provide the code?

Comment: What's the point of disposing a Task? It's not a resource or even a result. Where is your code? What leak are you talking about? The garbage collector will collect finished tasks eventually - *when they finish*

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem => https://dotnetfiddle.net/WXlRV3

Comment: I wasn't awaiting it before storing it in a variable; the variable was of type Task so it should be disposable according to the framework source. I can see in dotMemory that there are literally millions of `TimerQueueTimer` instances, each holding a reference to a `DelayPromise` instance. I am guessing these are created by `setTimeout` calls in AngleSharp, each of which starts a new `Task.Delay` task. It appears that long timeouts are holding these `DelayPromise` instances in memory long after the class starting them is released.

Answer (score -3):

[interesting](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5abebcdc-7189-4cc1-a4ed-269a970d0201/creating-a-custom-systemthreadingtaskstask-object?forum=netfxbcl)

> the task delegate is only accessible through the constructor for Task
>   that takes a delegate, you do not have access to a 'this' pointer when
>   constructing the delegate code.

Hope I help you **;)**

Comment: I'm not using a custom Task class. I'm just trying to `Dispose()` of the Task instance returned by `Task.Delay` when the method I'm in returns.

Comment: I refer that you can't, please read my substract in my first answer. But Why don't you void the object and call garbage collector instead of?. Sorry for my English :)